# Java class is ignored by activity layout when layout is inflated in other class

Tags: java, android, android-layout

So i've been working on my project, first android project to be specific, and i kinda progressed in stuff that  i want, i used fragments and all pretty successfully, but just recently i added a PopupWindow and use it as a window for displaying a music player in it, but when i created activity for that player and inflated the layout of this player activity in my other class, the main class that was created with player activity is now ignored, i checked with a button click event, and strangely, button click event is working when called from that other class where i inflated the layout of player activity, this is messy and all, but my question would be this - is there a way to inflate/show a popup window with a layout of my player activity while being able to have all methods and events in that same player activity java class? Here is a snippet that inflates layout from player activity:

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_play,null,false);
    popup = new PopupWindow(context);
    popup = new PopupWindow(layout, 480, 250, true);
    popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    popup.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animation);
    popup.showAtLocation(layout,Gravity.NO_GRAVITY,50,550);
```

The class that  i call it from extends ListFragment.
And here is a snippet from the player activity class that is ignored

```
public class PlayAct extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
    ImageButton imbPlay = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imbPlay);
    imbPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PlayAct.this);
            builder.setMessage("THIS IS A MESSAGE FROM NEW PLAYER ACTIVITY");
            builder.setTitle("MESSAGE");
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

I hope you can help me, and sorry if i posted something inccorectly as it's my first post on stackoverflow.

Comment: `the player activity class that is ignored` - what do you mean by "ignored"?

Comment: well, i mean that it's just not used at all, for example, i have a button in my layout, and i have a listener for this button in this class(ignored one), when i press it, nothing happens, but the same code works from class where i inflated this layout in(different class that shows a popup window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic concept is just consider that you have a layout file `hello.xml` and two java class one is `One.java` and other is `Two.java`. now you have a button in your `xml file` and also have the listener method "`clickButton`" in `One.java` class and `Two.java` . so which one is fired ? hear you need to configure(`inflate`) java class and layout file .suppose you inflate `hello.xml` with One.java so your listener method will goes to `One.java` class . But Yes you can write a method (for button's activity) in Two.java , then you need some additional task , you must make an object of `Two.java` class inside `One.java` class and just call this method inside buttons event method of `One.java` class . other wise nothing will happen . 
Thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot, you have turned me on the right path :), i actually got it figured now, thanks again.